# Spatial joining Geodataframes returns NAs

Tags: python, dataframe, spatial, geopandas

I am trying to spatially join two Geodataframes, with a left join however the second Geodataframe always had NA values. I would really appreciate some help in getting this right, here is what I have tried:

```
#1
police = pandas.read_csv("Police.csv")
#2
uk_boundary = pandas.read_csv("sf_boundary.csv")
#3
police_sf = geopandas.GeoDataFrame(
    police, geometry=geopandas.points_from_xy(x=police.Longitude, y=police.Latitude)
).set_crs(epsg=4326, inplace=True)
#4
uk_sf = geopandas.GeoDataFrame(
    uk_boundary, geometry=geopandas.points_from_xy(x=uk_boundary.Longitude, y=uk_boundary.Latitude)
).set_crs(epsg=4326, inplace=True)
#5
police_sf = police_sf.iloc[:,[4, 6]]
#6
uk_sf = uk_sf.iloc[:,[1, 4]]
join_pd = geopandas.sjoin(police_sf, uk_sf, how="left")
```

Example of the outcome dataset:

```
                            Crime.type                   geometry  \
0         Violence and sexual offences  POINT (-0.67902 50.78169)   
1                Anti-social behaviour  POINT (-2.51692 51.42368)   
2                Anti-social behaviour  POINT (-2.51277 51.41175)   
3                Anti-social behaviour  POINT (-2.51444 51.40934)   
4                             Burglary  POINT (-2.51507 51.41936)   
...                                ...                        ...   
18996750                   Other theft  POINT (-1.75903 50.99465)   
18996751                   Shoplifting  POINT (-1.75155 50.99285)   
18996752                   Shoplifting  POINT (-1.75155 50.99285)   
18996753  Violence and sexual offences  POINT (-1.74481 50.99320)   
18996754  Violence and sexual offences  POINT (-1.42572 51.03058)   

          index_right NAME  
0                 NaN  NaN  
1                 NaN  NaN  
2                 NaN  NaN  
3                 NaN  NaN  
4                 NaN  NaN  
...               ...  ...  
18996750          NaN  NaN  
18996751          NaN  NaN  
18996752          NaN  NaN  
18996753          NaN  NaN  
18996754          NaN  NaN
```

Some reproducible code of the two datasets:

```
#police dataset
{'Longitude': {1: -2.516919,2: -2.512773,3:   -2.514442,4: -2.515072,5: -2.49487,6: -2.512773,7: -2.495055,8: -2.516919,9: -2.512773,10: -2.495055,11: -2.495055,12: -2.509126,13: -2.495055,14: -2.509126,15: -2.504309,16: -2.498613,17: -2.497799,18: -2.498613,19: -2.498613},'Latitude': {1: 51.423683,2: 51.411751,3: 51.409343,4: 51.419357,5: 51.422276,6: 51.411751,7: 51.422132,8: 51.423683,9: 51.411751,10: 51.422132,11: 51.422132,12: 51.416137,13: 51.422132,14: 51.416137,15: 51.418801,16: 51.416002,17: 51.415233,18: 51.416002,19: 51.416002},'Crime.type': {1: 'Anti-social behaviour',2: 'Anti-social behaviour',3: 'Anti-social behaviour',4: 'Burglary',5: 'Criminal damage and arson',6: 'Criminal damage and arson',7: 'Drugs',8: 'Public order',9: 'Vehicle crime',10: 'Vehicle crime',11: 'Violence and sexual offences',12: 'Violence and sexual offences',13: 'Violence and sexual offences',14: 'Violence and sexual offences',15: 'Anti-social behaviour',16: 'Anti-social behaviour',17: 'Anti-social behaviour',18: 'Anti-social behaviour',19: 'Anti-social behaviour'}}

#map dataset
{'NAME': {1: 'Buckinghamshire',2: 'Buckinghamshire',3: 'Buckinghamshire',4: 'Buckinghamshire',5: 'Buckinghamshire',6: 'Buckinghamshire',7: 'Buckinghamshire',8: 'Buckinghamshire',9: 'Buckinghamshire',10: 'Buckinghamshire',11: 'Buckinghamshire',12: 'Buckinghamshire',13: 'Buckinghamshire',14: 'Buckinghamshire',15: 'Buckinghamshire',16: 'Buckinghamshire',17: 'Buckinghamshire',18: 'Buckinghamshire',19: 'Buckinghamshire'},'Longitude': {1: -0.500579742731822,2: -0.500562231052187,3: -0.500551492843239,4: -0.50060557136444,5: -0.50060719049165,6: -0.500600124159461,7: -0.500586635353007,8: -0.500565771696397,9: -0.500521784112314,10: -0.500121547252066,11: -0.499775648553165,12: -0.499629899275452,13: -0.499526010336186,14: -0.499516042742561,15: -0.49949926212727,16: -0.499472156394348,17: -0.499454478837858,18: -0.499422548303929,19: -0.499384521025904},'Latitude': {1: 51.5995448459169,2: 51.5994186801437,3: 51.5992603285579,4: 51.5988473256556,5: 51.5987547546975,6: 51.5986620736993,7: 51.5985908842995,8: 51.5985195116762,9: 51.5984092787353,10: 51.5976722454391,11: 51.5969555922043,12: 51.5966461998169,13: 51.5963814814086,14: 51.5959397929587,15: 51.5957012684416,16: 51.5954725894707,17: 51.5953949647129,18: 51.5953127525633,19: 51.5952421484913}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SJOINs require spatial relationships. Since the two data you want to sjoin are both points, you cannot capture the topological relationship between them. The default op of sjoin is intersect, so it should return only the intersecting part.